# Generating list sequence with a custom step in Python

Tags: python

Okay, i'm really stuck with that one-liner.

Yet tried to accomplish my task with zip and map, but none of it worked i want. So my question is: can i generate a list with a custom step like this?

```
>>wicked cool code snippet
>>[101, 105, 109, 115, 121]
```

The idea behind this is that i have the start of a sequence X equal to 101. 
Then i add 4, then again adding 4.
Then i add 6 to the previous result and again i add 6.

```
I believe it should look like this mathematically speaking:
```

An = A1+4d,A2+4d,A3+6d, A4+6d.

**UPD**

Ok, let me make it more clear.

> > > range(101, 120, 3) <-Classical arithmetical progression

```
[101, 104, 107, 110, 113, 116, 119] < - The output
```

What i need is a combination of two of them. Like add +4 to each element n-times, then add +6 to the last element of add 4 sequence n-times.

Hope, it's clearer now.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question in it's current form, because there is no obvious way the sequence should continue (should A5 and A6 use +8 instead of +6?) - if it continues at all.

Comment: Maybe do some functional operation on `101` and `[4, 4, 6, 6]`? I want to say fold using addition, except that goes all the way, so you'd have to do it in a range or something. Slightly beyond my brain ATM.

Comment: its not clear. what does 4 or 6 signify? length of the previous word?

Comment: You can't do that with just `zip` and `map`, some sort of accumulator must be involved.

Answer (score 2):

A bit hardcoded:

```
In [42]: step=[0,3,6,11,16]

In [43]: [i+step[n] for n, i in enumerate(range(101, 106))]
Out[43]: [101, 105, 109, 115, 121]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a wicked cool code snippet, but it returns your answer with one line of code:

```
 >>> map(lambda x: x+100 if x == 1 else (x+103 if x == 2 else (x+106 if x == 3 else (x+111 if x == 4 else x+116))), range(1,6))
 [101, 105, 109, 115, 121]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
>>> reduce(lambda acc, i: acc + [acc[-1] + i], [4,4,6,6], [101])
[101, 105, 109, 115, 121]
```

Unfortunately, it is not exactly what you've asked for and I am afraid it just can't be done with `map` and `zip` alone, because these operations do not involve any kind of accumulator.